# How to configure SpringBoot authentication for RestController

Tags: java, spring-boot, security, authentication, spring-restcontroller

I have a controller for users that contains

```
@PostMapping("/user/register")
public String register  ( @RequestParam String name
                        , @RequestParam String password
                        , @RequestParam String email
                        , HttpServletRequest request)

@GetMapping("/user/confirm/{token}")
public Optional<User> confirm(@PathVariable(value = "token") String token)
```

and

```
    @PostMapping("/user/login")
public ResponseEntity<String> login 
                            ( @RequestParam String email
                            , @RequestParam String password
                            , HttpServletRequest request
                            ){
    //System.out.println("post:/user/login email="+email);
    User user = userService.login(email, password);
    if (user==null)
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true); // createSession=true
    session.setAttribute(SESSION_USER, user);
    
    **cfgSecurity.setAthenticated(session, user);**
    
    return ResponseEntity.ok("OK");
}
```

Users have a role that is an enum.
The question is how to configure security.
Here is my configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CfgSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    private static final String PRINCIPAL  = "admin";
    private static final String CREDENTIAL = "password";
    @Autowired AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception { // authentication
        auth
          .inMemoryAuthentication()
          .withUser(PRINCIPAL).password(passwordEncoder().encode(CREDENTIAL))
          .roles(roles());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { // resource security
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .httpBasic()
            /*
            .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user/register").permitAll()//.hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/user/confirm/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                
            //.and().formLogin().loginPage("/user/login").permitAll()
             */
          ;
    }
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception
    {
        //https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/docs/?api=org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
    private static String[] roles() {
        String[] array = new String[Role.values().length];
        for (Role role : Role.values()) {
            array[role.ordinal()] = role.name();
        }
        return array;
    }

    public void setAthenticated(HttpSession session, User user) {
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664893/how-to-manually-set-an-authenticated-user-in-spring-security-springmvc
        try {
            Authentication authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        (PRINCIPAL, passwordEncoder().encode(CREDENTIAL)
                        , user.getAuthorities()
                        );
            Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(authRequest);
            
            SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
            securityContext.setAuthentication(authentication);
            session.setAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT", securityContext);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

It does not work : I get
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials.

Here is User.getAuthorities (referenced in setAuthenticated) :

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {

```
final SimpleGrantedAuthority simpleGrantedAuthority = 
        new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.toString());
return Collections.singletonList(simpleGrantedAuthority);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way it works: use the encrypted password for AuthenticationManagerBuilder but pass it unencrypted to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.

```
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception { 
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser(PRINCIPAL).password(passwordEncoder().encode(CREDENTIAL))
        .roles(roles());
}

public void setAthenticated(HttpSession session, User user) {
    Authentication authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        (PRINCIPAL, CREDENTIAL, user.getAuthorities());
    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager
                                      .authenticate(authRequest);
            
    SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    securityContext.setAuthentication(authentication);
    session.setAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT", securityContext);
}
```